# Vuejs: Laravel Mix

Tags: vue.js

Estoy probando Vuejs con laravel mix.

Acabo de crear mi component se llama HeaderComponent.vue, lo estoy renderizando bien se me muestra en el home de la pagina pero quiero hacer lo siguiente:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- Just an image -->
        <nav class="navbar">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img :src="{{ img }}" alt="Mercantil Logo" />
            </a>           
        </nav>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: function() {
      return {
        //Quiero que la ruta que escriba aqui se renderice en el template
        img: "img/menu/1.png"
      };
    }
  };
</script>

<style lang=""></style>
```

Como escribí en el comentario del código quiero que lo que escriba en img se renderice en el src de la imagen, pero me da error, como debo hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Qué error te da?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al usar `:src=""` (equivalente a `vbind:src=""`) no necesitar encerrar la expresion entre `{{ }}` usalo directamente

```
<img :src="img" alt="Mercantil Logo" />
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes

Comment: Ojo vuejs ya va en la versión 2 y próximo la 3, deberías recomendarle doc actualizada

Comment: Actualmente Laravel sigue trabajando con la versión 2, así que voy bien con ella, muchas gracias.